# Не публикуется файл

Tags: c#

Так выглядит параметры публикации

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так выглядят `cspoj` файл

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>7.0.4</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>
```

После нажатия "Опубликовать" проект бесконечно публикуется и выдаёт ошибку через некоторое время:

```
3>------ Начало публикации: проект: Calculator, Конфигурация: Release Any CPU ------
3>Определение проектов для восстановления...
3>Не удалось скачать пакет "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Runtime.win-x64.7.0.4" из "https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.windowsdesktop.app.runtime.win-x64/7.0.4/microsoft.windowsdesktop.app.runtime.win-x64.7.0.4.nupkg".
3>Не удается прочитать данные из транспортного соединения: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.
3>  Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
```

При попытке вручную установить `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Runtime.win-x64.7.0.4` из NuGet, появляется ошибка о том, что "имеет тип dotnetplatform который несовместим с этим проектом"

Comment: RuntimeFrameworkVersion можно убрать

Comment: @aepot Убрал. Не помогло

Comment: Какая версия Windows?

Comment: @aepot Windows 10 Pro 22H2 19045.2364

Comment: Странно, почему NuGet рвет соединение, думал винда несвежая, тогда сдаюсь